# What is the relation between $\lVert{Hp}\rVert^2$ and $\lVert{H}\rVert$ when $Hp\ne0$ and $\lVert{p}\rVert = 1$?

Tags: vectors

What is the relation between $\lVert{Hp}\rVert^2$ and $\lVert{H}\rVert$ when $Hp\ne0$ and $\lVert{p}\rVert = 1$?

Note that $H$ and $p$ are sampled value of Gaussian distributed random variables, in which $H$ is a vector with a size of $1$ by $N$ and $p$ is a vector with a size of $N$ by $1$?

I think $$\lVert{Hp}\rVert^2 = \lVert{H}\rVert.$$
However, I failed to prove the above equation.
Is my thought wrong?
Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

All you can state is
$$\|Hp\|^2 \ \le\ \|H\|^2$$
Can you prove this one?

Comment: Actually, I tried many times using MATLAB program. I could observe that the value of RHS is much larger than that of LHS.

Comment: Well, by compactness of the unit sphere, there exists a unit vector $p$ such that $\|Hp\|=\|H\|$..

Comment: However, to prove $\lVert Hp\rVert^2 \le \lVert H\rVert^2$, do we have to prove that there do not exist $p$ such that $\lVert Hp\rVert^2 \ge \lVert H\rVert^2$? Intuitively, each element of $p$ must be less than $1$, so each element of $Hp$ MAY be less than or equal to that of $H$. Is it enough to prove the above equation? I am not sure that it is enough.